# LWRP Custom Shader Graph material casts no shadow

Tags: unity, shaders, shadows

I created an empty Shader Graph by clicking Create -> Shaders -> PBR Graph.

I created the material for this shader and assigned it to my game object, but the object does not cast a shadow.

If I assign the default LWRP Lit material, then everything works and the shadows are dropped, but with a custom shader there is no shadow.

How can I make my custom shader material cast shadows?

Comment: I have not been able to reproduce the issue you describe. Creating a new PBR shader graph, leaving it unchanged, and assigning it to objects in my scene has not interfered with their shadows. A [similar question on UnityAnswers](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1602961/getting-shadows-with-all-shaders-except-shadergrap.html) suggests that this might be a bug you can resolve by deleting & recreating your lightweight render pipeline asset. Have you tried this?

Comment: https://forum.unity.com/threads/lwrp-shader-graph-custom-shader-casts-no-shadow.683743/
Hi, More information about this

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it for me:

If you use a transparent surface type on standard LWRP or UniversalRP (that does not cast shadows), then change that material to a custom shadergraph's shader, you lose shadow casting. Just use a lit shader for the new pipelines, set it to Opaque, then change it to your custom shader.

e.g. set it to Lit (universal Render Pipeline/Lit)
[image]
and change it back to your custom shader afterwards